# Can I travel through the Schengen area if my passport expires in less than 6 months?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, netherlands

I am traveling to Prague from Los Angeles. My travels end on 15 April and passport expires 14 October. 
Netherlands requires 6 months of validity after end of travel, 
Czech requires 3 months validity after end of travel. 
Will I be allowed to continue to my flight from Amsterdam to Prague given the passport does not quite meet the 6 month requirement for my layover?

Comment: @pnuts irrelevant, unless OP is an EU/EEA citizen

Comment: Where do you get the idea that the Netherlands requires six months after the end of travel?  From the [consular website](http://www.the-netherlands.org/shared/products-and-services/products-and-services/schengen-visa/entering-the-netherlands-or-the-schengen-area-without-a-visa): "That passport or travel document must cover your intended stay and remain valid for at least three months after your intended date of departure."

Comment: "Netherlands requires 6 months of validity after end of travel". **No it does not!** See my answer

Comment: @Crazydre technically you will need 6 months validity if you want to stay for the full 90 days. I think some websites are simply too lazy to spell out the nuances.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not 6 months after the end of travel, which is what OP wrote

Answer (score 3):

The entire Schengen area has a unified set of rules for third-country nationals so your point of entry is irrelevant. According to the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399):

> For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following:
>
> (a) they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the holder to cross the border satisfying the following criteria:
>
> (i) **its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended date of departure from the territory of the Member States**. In a justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;

Therefore the answer is that you may enter the Schengen area with a soon-to-expire passport, as long as you plan to depart at least 3 months before your travel document expires.

Comment: I will like to add that according to the US State Department https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/netherlands.html  Passport should be valid for **at least six months beyond your planned date of departure**. It mentions that some SCHENGEN countries implement the requirements haphazardly and enforce six months.

Comment: @pnuts The US website said 6 months of validity beyond date of departure to the Schengen country. Basically three months stay plus three months after end of travel _NOT_ six months after end of travel

Comment: @Pnuts For Germany however you are right _Your passport should be valid for at least six months beyond the period of stay.  This regulation is strictly enforced in Germany_. https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/germany.html

Comment: @SheikPaul the US government's statements about passport validity requirements of other governments are not authoritative, and, in this case, not correct.  The [German consulate](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/Schengen_20Visa.html) says "on the planned date of departure from Germany, your passport should have at least another three months validity."

Comment: @phoog I think we should bear in mind the situation. The chances that you can talk down a power tripping immigration officer are slim and none. Thus for me if the US government website indicates that some countries are applying the rule wrongly and then goes on to list how particular countries apply it, I would err on the side of caution and believe they know what they are talking about. Nobody is going to be there with you when you're being denied entry and your rights are only worth so much. My $0.02

Comment: @SheikPaul Why would you believe the US government web site when the German government describes *its own rules* differently?

Comment: **No, no, just no!** Timatic clearly states that 3 months is all that's required, so anything else is outdated info

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=PA&COUNTRY=nl&SUBSECTION=VA&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines, about the Netherlands:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of **3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay**.

This is the information for the **Netherlands**, which is where you will clear immigration. As such it is the Dutch, **not** Czech, requirements that are relevant for you in practice.

Nevertheless, for the sake of it, [**here**](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=PA&COUNTRY=cz&SUBSECTION=VA&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) is what it says about Czech:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of **3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay**

Same thing there in other words

So, any info suggesting 6 months is required by the Netherlands is outdated.