# Am I eligible for a Schengen visa if my passport will expire in 3 months?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, vfs-global

I have planned a trip to Germany from India for 3 weeks from 3rd April 2019 to 23 April 2019.
But I just checked my passport validity expires on 20th July, 2019. Will I get Schengen visa or not.

Though, I have seen below answer,

> For intended stays on the territory of the Member States of a duration
>   of no more than 90 days in any 180-day period, which entails
>   considering the 180-day period preceding each day of stay, the entry
>   conditions for third-country nationals shall be the following: (a)
>   they are in possession of a valid travel document entitling the holder
>   to cross the border satisfying the following criteria:
>
> (i) its validity shall extend at least three months after the intended
>   date of departure from the territory of the Member States. In a
>   justified case of emergency, this obligation may be waived;
>
> (ii) it shall have been issued within the previous 10 years;

as per above answer my departure date is 23rd April and Visa should be more than 23July But mine expires on 20th July. Will it be ok If rebook my flight return ticket on 20th April to get the visa. Or is it fine it is just 2-3 days lesser than expected.

In case not, then what are the workaround or any other solution that might help. As I have already made all the bookings.

Comment: Get a new passport? You will need it soon, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The rules are very clear.

Your passport must be valid 3 months **beyond** the duration of stay in the Schengen area for which you don’t qualify

If you made your return on the 19th you may be approved but what happened to me before was that my wife was rejected even though her intended return was a clear week before the 3 months period but they still denied and asked for a new passport to be made.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to Germany with this condition. my last day in germany was 23th Arpil and passport was about to expire in next 93 days. So, I think it is safe to travel if passport is valid for next 90 days. Though, You should not wait for such conditions rather be proactive and get your passport renewed.

Answer (score -4):

I'm afraid the answer is no. Normally, visas require at least 6 months of remaining validity on your passport. You should renew it before applying, this is my advice. 
My girlfriend is from Russia and when applying for a Schengen Area visa, among the requirements she found the passport remaining validity of at least 6 months.

Comment: *Normally, visas require at least 6 months of remaining validity on your passport* This is not the rule for the Schengen area. OP has correctly quoted what the rule is.

Comment: @MJeffryes, can you post the correct information in an answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: @Willeke I don't think that the information I posted is really an answer to the question. The answer is "no, there isn't a workaround". The rules about what validity is required for Schengen is posted here already https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88021/can-i-travel-through-the-schengen-area-if-my-passport-expires-in-less-than-6-mon